# particles flying far away from the emitter

Tags: objects, particles, physics, keyframes, error

I am following Ian Hubert's lazy moth tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imkSdlbXB_U). Everything was going well until the particle system part. My moths are just exploding and flying very far from the object or the leader they are supposed to follow. I have tried copying the exact settings as in the video and tried some of mine own, nothing changes. They disappear into the void after 3 frames.

I did succeed in a completely new save file, but I just used cubes as moths.

[image: Frame 1]

[image: Frame 2]

[image: Frame 3]

[image: Frame 4]

https://we.tl/t-YA2YZpDRz4 - Blend file link. Was not sure about other ways to add it here.

Comment: please provide blend file so we can check it out

Comment: Added a link to blend file download in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your scene was quite big and you had a lot of "stuff" set to "don't show in viewport" but this doesn't mean that this stuff does not affect your simulation!

So, change the weight to 1, delete everything in your collection except:

[image]

Increase scale a bit and the lifetime then you get this...

Result:

[image]

I didn't want to waste my time to much to find out what exactly the reason is because you had a lot of objects - some had collisions (which might influence the particles), you have two wind forces - which do influence particles and so on.

So still your task to do:
delete one object by one and check, when your simulation is running to find out, what objects are causing this unwanted behaviour of your simulation.

Comment: They still fly away from the lamp in a big chunk :(

Comment: yes, they fly away, but the exploding problem is solved, right? this is what i tried to solve.

Comment: you're right, thank you

Comment: i updated my answer. If my answer helped you, please check the checkmark left to my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much dude, you really took your time to help, respect!